# No callback for IOS Firebase Facebook Login FUIFacebookAuth

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, firebase

I am having issues with the callback from Facebook login using Firebase's pre-built login system. This was working a last week and I have not changed anything around the login area that would have broke this. The login gets all the way to the Facebook confirmation screen and after I click the Continue button, the spinner shows but never finishes the callback. I am not sure if Firebase or Facebook updated something about the login but it appears to now be broken for me.

Xcode: 11.3

Swift: 4.2

Pod Imports:

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/Auth'
pod 'FirebaseUI/Google'
pod 'FirebaseUI/Facebook'
```

App Delegat

```
import Firebase

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        FirebaseApp.configure()
        SVProgressHUD.setDefaultMaskType(.clear)
        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = FirebaseApp.app()?.options.clientID

        monitorReachability()
       // IAPHelper.start

        let opened = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: PREF_OPENED) as? Bool ?? false
        if (!opened) {
            UIApplication.shared.setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval(3600 * 24)
        }
        completeThePendingTransactions()

        return true
    }
```

Sign In VC

```
import Firebase
import FirebaseUI

func launchFirebaseLogin() {
        // Action to perform after sign-in is successful
        handle = Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { (auth, user) in
            if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil {
                let firebaseUser: Firebase.User? = Auth.auth().currentUser
                self.doSignIn(user: firebaseUser, firstName: (firebaseUser?.displayName)!, photoURL: (firebaseUser!.photoURL!.absoluteString))
                return
            } else {
                let authUI = FUIAuth.defaultAuthUI()
                authUI?.delegate = self
                let providers: [FUIAuthProvider] = [
                    FUIGoogleAuth(),
                    FUIFacebookAuth()
                ]

                authUI?.providers = providers
                let authViewController = authUI!.authViewController()
                self.present(authViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The problem appears to be with a particular Facebook account. If I try a different account, it works fine. I have not figured out exactly how to resolve the issue with the account that is hanging, but at least the code is not broken. I believe it may be issues with caching somewhere. It may be corrupt caching on Facebook's side.

Comment: I was able to reproduce the problem and solve the issue. The problem was that I was logging in with both Google and Facebook. If you login with Facebook, then Google, then try to go back to Facebook, it hangs on the Facebook login. The only way to fix this was to delete the user in Firebase associated to that email address for the Facebook account and then login again with Facebook.

Comment: you sir is a god damned Genius !! I would expect Firebase would put this type if flaw in a HUGE BOLD LETTERS. spent hours on this :(